# procedure for comparing results of two sql statements

Tags: mysql

1)Below is the code I'm trying for a procedure where I need to compare the count from two different tables. (tbl1 and tbl2 are in parameters to be passed).
But in the above code the values for 'a' and 'b' are set as statements. I need the resultant value(count) from the two statements to compare in the 'IF' condition.

```
declare a integer;
declare b integer;

set @a:=concat('select count(*) from ', tbl1);
/*PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
execute stmt1;
deallocate PREPARE stmt1;*/

set @b:= concat('select count(*) from ', tbl2);
/*PREPARE stmt2 FROM @b;
execute stmt2;
deallocate PREPARE stmt2;*/


 if
 @a=@b
 then 
 select 1;
 else
 select 2;
 end if;
```

2) Actually where I am facing a problem to set 'tbl1' and 'tbl2' as parameters in procedure.
The below code works fine if the table names are given directly, but i need them as parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc (in tbl1 varchar(50), in tbl2 varchar(50))

declare a integer;
declare b integer;

set @a:=(select count(*) from tbl1);
/*PREPARE stmt1 FROM @a;
execute stmt1;
deallocate PREPARE stmt1;*/

set @b:= (select count(*) from tbl2);
/*PREPARE stmt2 FROM @b;
execute stmt2;
deallocate PREPARE stmt2;*/

if
@a=@b
then 
select 1;
else
select 2;
end if;
```

Hope anyone out there can help me with the solution.

Comment: what is wrong with above code? it seems right...

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please explain a little more. Seems like you are complicating things.

Comment: 1) Why do you have variable table names?  This is usually an indication of a badly denormalised schema.  2) This feels like business logic - does it really belong in the database?

Comment: I need the count of tables in the variables so that I can compare them in IF statement. The tables will be parameters.

Comment: @ eggyal
I need to use this procedure at different places.

Comment: I suggest you read about the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) - the information you have provided, both in your question and in your responses to our comments, leaves a very unclear picture of what it is you're trying to do.  Please provide wider context.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, it is likely that you shouldn't be doing this at all... but, for what it's worth:

```
SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `',REPLACE('`','``',tbl1),'`
) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `',REPLACE('`','``',tbl2),'`
);');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @sql := NULL;
```

`REPLACE()` has been used to try and avoid SQL injection (it's somewhat crude, but it's the best one can do without further information).